# Create unique constraint on two columns in two tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, unique-constraint

Here is my data model.

[image: data-model]

I need to make the `username` column in the `USER` table as a unique column. But it should be unique with the company.

For example, **Company A** can have a username as **James** and **Company B** also can have a username as **James**.

To achieve this, my opinion is to make a `unique constraint` with `username` and `company_id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your database adding company_id to users. then add a unique index (company_id,username) to your table.

```
user
----
user_id     (PK)
company_id  (UNIQUE INDEX)
emplyee_id
email
username    (UNIQUE INDEX)
password
```

BUT i think you do not need a many to many relation,
could be a good idea to change your database removing the many to many reaction in this way:

```
company
-------
company_id  (PK)
company_name

user
----
user_id     (PK)
company_id  
emplyee_id
email
username
password
```

Comment: Thanks Danilo. Will this change affect to normalization of the database?

Comment: i think this change is before normalization, i propose to change the entity relation model adding a constraint: a user can only work in one company.

Answer (score 1):

From the data model, it is clear that, a user can belong to multiple companies and a company can have multiple users. So adding company_id to USER table will cause USER table to explode with lots of redundant user data for each company instance. The USER_COMPANY entity exists specifically to avoid this.

It is not advisable to handle this requirement using data model changes. The best way to handle this requirement is through application code or triggers.

The least inefficient way to achieve this through data model changes will be, to add username column in user_company table and synchronise user and user_company table for the user_name column across all DMLs throughout the application. That will again require lots of application code.

So the best solution is to leave it to the application and not disturb a good data model.

Hope this helps.